# web3 contract instantiation

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, solc, abi

I'm trying to create a `contract` object with web3.

```
      var contract_abi = result['contracts']['Test']["interface"];

//[{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"inc","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"odd","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Incremented","type":"event"}];

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract_abi);
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object.
```

However if I copy my contract_abi console output and directly create a variable like so:

```
var contract_abi =
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"inc","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"odd","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Incremented","type":"event"}];
```

It works. Whats going on? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if your abi is correct.But I am writing the way of interacting with smart contract and generating abi from source code.

**Generating abi from Source code:**

- Paste your code in [remix-online solidity compiler.](http://remix.ethereum.org)
- Click on start to compile to compile your code.
- If your code is compiled successfully. CLick on `Details` tab on upper right corner
- You will a list of properties including abi, copy the abi from there.

**Accessing contract using web3:**

- Initialise web3 instance
- Use following code to get an instance of contract.

> ```
> //For web3 versions 0.20.x
> var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
> //For web3 1.0.x
> var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi,contractAddress);
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please, which version of web3? The method `contract` doesn't exist in the latest at least, it isn't listed in the [API docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#contract). There's only the Contract class, so the `new` keyword is needed, just as @user339946 used in the question description.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue and was able to resolve it by running JSON.parse() on the interface result, so in your case it would be something like:

```
var contract_abi = JSON.parse(result['contracts']['Test']["interface"])
```

the reason that copying the output of your command line and setting it to the variable is working is because when you copy it, you technically change it from a string to an object, which is what JSON.parse would do :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For me I was not retrieving the abi object from the compiled json file.

this worked:

```
var erc20ABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file+"DummyERC20.json"));
var abi = erc20ABI.abi #essential
ERC20DummyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(erc20ABI, erc20Address);
```

Comment: Adding .abi fixed it for me on `1.0.0-beta.37`

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. If you are using web3@1.0 and JavaScript, you probably need to run your ABI with JSON.parse().

Check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)